# How can I split WAV into smaller WAV files?

Tags: java, android, wav

I have an android application, which records WAV files. This files can be up to 3 minutes long, but I need to split them by 30 seconds (This smaller WAV's must be playable too). I don't really care if it is splitted on a silent moment or not. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use AudioInputStream and its AudioFileFormat member (which contains an AudioFormat instance) to know what to write (format, sample rate), you can use AudioSystem to write it.

Based on the sample rate of the format you can find out how many bytes of audio are 30 seconds, and go on a loop of reading that many bytes from the AudioInputStream, writing them to a new file.